# "Tears Up" pills not working

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I found a *Tears Up* pill and copied it a whole bunch of times with *Jera* + *Blank Card*. After eating an entire double room of pills, my Tears stat is only at 3 and Isaac is not visibly firing faster.
Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I've noticed some effects don't appear to take, well, effect, until I leave the room. Maybe that'll help here?

Comment: A side effect of Eve's Mascara, perhaps? Or maybe a bug in the new version.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've tried the pills on multiple floors and still they have no effect. I did dupe luck up pills and those worked fine.

Comment: Maybe it's due to a particular item you've picked up. Do you remember your tears "upgrades"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a ceiling value for your base tear rate, but this can be modified by what items you pick up. Eve's Mascara, Polyphemus, The Inner Eye, and Mutant Spider will reduce your tear rate by a given modifier. Your rate of tears is dependent both on your base rate and the modifier.

Also, the tears stat is a bit odd in that maxing it out through normal means will not show up as a maxed stat on the stats screen. The only way to get that max level tears stat is through Soy Milk, but that massive damage reduction doesn't usually make that worth it.

Generally speaking you shouldn't count on the stat screen to be perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that *Tear Rate* is measured in the delay from one tear fired to the next, increasing the stat decreases this delay.

Tears do not have a maximum value, but there is a so called "soft-cap". After certain set values are reached the benefits gained from this stat start to decrease. This means that after a bunch of *Tears Up* pills eaten you won't see any improvement.

Your *Tear Rate* dependes on two factors: *Basic Tears Stat* and *Delay*.

- **Basic Tears Stat** is a stat which affects the final fire rate
- **Delay** is the number of frames between each shot, and depends on *Basic Tears Stat*

Since there are 60 frames per second, the final *Fire Rate* (measured in tears per second) is simply 60 divided by the *Delay*.
Note, however, that since the *Delay* has to be a whole number (presumably), the *Fire Rate* can only be specific numbers.

---

Note:
In the previous Binding of Isaac **Tears Rate** was "capped" at 6 tears per second, so presumably there's a cap value in the remake, too.

Comment: I wasn't shooting very fast at all. When I looked at stats, there were only 3 bars in the tears stat.

Comment: Have you picked up any tears modifying item? Anyway don't trust the stat bars too much, I can't understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a cap on how high your permanent stats can get from pills, but if you are not noticing any change at all, then that is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a soft cap for tears, at 3. You need soy milk or almond milk to increase that further.

Comment: Any source for that value?

Comment: https://bindingofisaac.fandom.com/wiki/Stats/Tears

Comment: You should add them to your future answers, it's appreciated if you can support your statements.